# How to implement this symbolic summation in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement this summation, any help, please?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Arfdl.png)

Comment: Hi! Please provide some context of your problem, show your research effort and code attempt
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that x is a list of numbers, this can be written as following:

```
H = '+'.join([f'x{i}*x{i+1}' for i in range(1, 21)])

>>>print(H)
'x1*x2+x2*x3+x3*x4+x4*x5+x5*x6+x6*x7+x7*x8+x8*x9+x9*x10+x10*x11+x11*x12+x12*x13+x13*x14+x14*x15+x15*x16+x16*x17+x17*x18+x18*x19+x19*x20+x20*x21'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I need to implement it symbolically, i.e., I expect to get H=x1*x2 + x2*x3 + x3*x4.......

Comment: Code updated, please check again

Answer (score 0):

You need a computer algebra system (CAS). There are a number of software packages in Python that implements CAS, for example, using `sympy`:

```
from sympy import *
i = symbols('i')
x = IndexedBase('x')
H = Sum(x[i] * x[i-1], (i, 1, 20))
```

This will produce H, a symbolic expression the represents the equation in your image.

Or, you can use `summation` instead to evaluate the `Sum` into a series of additions:

```
H_evaluated = summation(x[i] * x[i-1], (i, 1, 20))
```

or call the `doit()` function:

```
H_evaluated == H.doit()
```

You can try sympy online on https://live.sympy.org/ to play with sympy without installing it locally. [Try this equation live](https://live.sympy.org/?evaluate=i%20%3D%20symbols(%27i%27%2C%20integer%3DTrue)%0A%23--%0Ax%20%3D%20IndexedBase(%27x%27)%0A%23--%0AH%20%3D%20Sum(x%5Bi%5D%20*%20x%5Bi-1%5D%2C%20(i%2C%201%2C%2020))%0A%23--%0AH%0A%23--%0AH.doit()%0A%23--%0A)